# Reading from a file in c

Tags: c

A part of this C code is bugging me, and I can't see what I am doing wrong. I am not trying to get someone to write the complete code, since this is my homework assignment, but I would really like to know what am I doing wrong here. So this is a part of main:

```
FILE *fp,*fd;
fp=fopen("test1.txt","r");
if (fp==NULL)
    return -1;
fd=fopen("test2.txt","w");
if (fd==NULL)
    return -2;
while (fp != EOF){
    fread(fd,1,10,fp);
}
//read_copy(fp,fd);
fclose(fp);
fclose(fd);
return 0;
```

And I can't seem to figure out why it doesn't work. With while written like this, it goes into an infinite loop. If I try to put a `fscanf()` in while, it gives me `seg fault`. So what am I doing wrong?
Thx!

Answer (score 1):

The `fread()` function only accepts *one* argument of type `FILE *`.

You're essentially overwriting the C library's internal file representation with data from the file.

See any [basic reference](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fread) for the proper prototype for `fread()`. You need a buffer, something like:

```
char buffer[1024];

fread(buffer, 1, sizeof buffer, fp);
```

Also, you must of course check the return value of `fread()`. Further, I would suggest using better names than `fd` and `fp`, they're pretty opaque.

Comment: but the problem is, this way it goes in an infinite loop. What I want is to write from one file to another..

Answer (score 1):

This should help: [In C, how should I read a text file and print all strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3463426/in-c-how-should-i-read-a-text-file-and-print-all-strings)

When using

```
 fwrite(buf, 1, nread, stdout);
```

The stdout is the output stream. You can use a file stream ( FILE * ) instead of stdout.

Answer (score 0):

You need to read the data into a buffer and write it out. Something like:

```
FILE *in, *out;
char buffer[SZ]; /* Define some size */
int nrd;

/* Do the whole dance opening files, etc */

while((nrd = fread(buffer, 1, SZ,  in)) > 0)
    fwrite(buffer, 1, nrd, out);

/* If nrd == 0 --> Reached EOF
   If nrd <  0 --> Some kind of error */
```

The condition in the `while` tries to read up to `SZ` bytes and checks what came of it, the `fwrite` writes out what was read. Check the manual pages.