# Getting error when reading from file

Tags: c, file-io, char

Whenever i try to read the char from file and try to access it i am getting error . My code is :

```
while((c=fgetc(f))!=EOF) {
  if(c == '\n') {
    str[i]='\0';

    Info* inf = new Info();
    inf->getInputFromFile(str);
    if((table->insert(inf))==0)
    cout<<"exist."<<endl;
    //delete inf;

    for(int j =0; j<50;j++)
    str[j]='\0';

    i=0;

  } else {
    str[i] = c;
    i++;
}
```

But here when ever I try to give a dummy word such as : `inf->getInputFromFile("Hello");`
I am not getting any error. I can't also find the error using debuggin because when I press F8(CodeBlocks IDE) my debugger start and it doesn't stop any line. i.e. i don't find any error when running the program using F8.

Here is the input file content :

```
int, INTEGER
myFunction, FUNCTION
x, IDENTIFIER
5, NUMBER
x, Identity
char, CHARACTER
fl, FLOAT
dbl, DOUBLE
you, MEINTHIS
dlt, DELETE
hel, HELLOWORLD
string, STRING
```

Comment: so what should i do . Use EOF in next to while in If case?

Comment: Should i use instead this : while(1){
                c=fgetc(f));
                if(c == EOF){
                    break;
                }

Comment: Where are you getting the error?

Comment: I can't find out . Because i can't open it in debug mode. May be it is with the string as if i give this inf->getInputFromFile("Hello"); all things go right

Comment: If so, add printfs at the beginning of if, else, and while loop. Also, the problem might be that you do not end your string, if file ends without `\n` at the end of every line.

Comment: There are too many missing details within the question, which are required in order to detect the exact problem at hand, so will just give you a few advices: 1. Function `fgetc` returns an `int`, so declare variable `c` as such, and cast it to `char` where needed (if I'm not mistaken, `EOF` is an `int` and that could get your `while` loop running forever). 2. There doesn't seem to be any point in that `for` loop. 3. Are you sure you've opened the file (pointed by `f`) for reading?

Comment: Can you tell me what other thing needed for clarificaiton. Cause i have tried ^ mention way but no result.

Comment: What are you doing here: `Info* inf = new Info();`? C doesn't have the `new` keyword. Edit: OK, I see: you are using C++. Then update your qestion tags.

Comment: Problem is not clear.

Comment: Describe the error you are receiving.

Answer (score 0):

How to read a file in C was answered here: [In C, how should I read a text file and print all strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3463426/in-c-how-should-i-read-a-text-file-and-print-all-strings) And I think that's the answer you are searching for.

Comment: I have used it  but still the problem exist