# Reading lines from a file using c program

Tags: c

```
#include "stdio.h"

int main(){
    char str[20];
    while(scanf("%19[^\n]",str)==1){
        printf("%s",str);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Compiled using:

```
$ gcc file.c -o file
$ file < input.txt
```

The program is reading only first line from the file `input.txt` :

```
hello this is
a test that
should make it
happen
```

I want the program to read the complete file, please help

Comment: Read that : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3463426/in-c-how-should-i-read-a-text-file-and-print-all-strings and never use scanf.

Comment: What is `[^\n]`? Is that an attempt at a “not a newline” character class regex in a `scanf()` format string?

Comment: @Emmet Character classes are supported by `scanf`. They look similar to regex character classes.

Comment: actually i wanted to use this to write a c program that reads another c program and creates it flow graph. i assume here that the file does not contain any error and code is written according to LOC

Comment: @interjay: so they are! And have been for years. I never knew that. I guess that's what you get for not even looking at `scanf()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a space:

```
while(scanf(" %19[^\n]",str)==1){
             ^
```

The space (unintuitively) consumes *any* white-space, including the `\n`, which otherwise you are not handling.

Of course, it is generally better to use e.g. `fgets()` and `sscanf()` rather than `scanf()` to parse input.

This changes the logic of you code slightly, but maybe better captures your intent. Any attempt to only skip only `\n` rather than all white-space, as in:

```
while(scanf("%19[^\n]\n",str)==1){
```

will fail, because here the second `\n` is exactly the same as a space .

Comment: thank u :) it worked , but why is space needed ??

Comment: The space (unintuitively) consumes any white-space, including the `\n', which otherwise you are not handling.

Comment: @user3433752: As a minor improvement, it is generally better to use `#include <stdio.h>` rather than `#include "stdio.h"`. BTW, +1 for the use of `19` in your `scanf`.

Comment: actually i wanted to use this to write a c program that reads another c program and creates it flow graph and then dd path graph. i assume here that the file does not contain any error and code is written according to LOC , can you suggest a nice efficient way to do that(if u don't mind)

Answer (score 0):

Find the modified code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char str[20];
    while(gets(str)!=NULL)
    {
      printf("%s",str);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do not use `gets` as it will lead to buffer overflow. Use `fgets`.

Comment: Isn't `gets()` officially deprecated? IIRC, it's even been removed from `stdio` by C11.