# Using system calls in C to open a file

Tags: c, linux, unix

I want to open a `.txt` file using a C program. Now the thing I am searching is how to open this file from a C program using a *system call*, e.g. `open`.

Comment: I pasted "[how to open this file from a C PROGRAM using a system call. e.g open](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+open+this+file+from+a+C+PROGRAM+using+a+system+call.+e.g+open&oq=how+to+open+this+file+from+a+C+PROGRAM+using+a+system+call.+e.g+open&aqs=chrome..69i57.299j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8)" into google and it found [this tutorial with example](http://www.techytalk.info/linux-system-programming-open-file-read-file-and-write-file/comment-page-1/). Is that any help?

Comment: similar Stack question and answers:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3463426/in-c-how-should-i-read-a-text-file-and-print-all-strings

Comment: Either you are writing a Bash script or a C program, but it can't be both.  I removed the [tag:bash] stuff but if you can explain how it's relevant, please do edit your question to add it back.

Comment: Use a system call, e.g. `open`.

Comment: In the meantime, if you have a concrete text processing problem you want to solve, you can probably learn Awk and solve it in less time than it takes to write and debug your first C program. Unless you specifically want to learn C or absolutely need the fastest possible program, I would take two steps back.

Comment: It seems to me you answered your own question. `open()` is a syscall.

Comment: Keep in mind using syscalls to read files on disk can be very inneficient because syscalls are very basic and don't offer any kind of buffering like `fopen()` does. If you use `read()` to read 1 byte, it will read 1 byte from disk, if you read another byte, there it goes to the disk again to fetch the next byte, its very inneficient.

Answer (score 0):

Using [`open()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/open) system call you can open the file you need.

```
int open(const char *pathname, int flags);
```

It will return the file descriptor for doing the operation in that file.

Or else you can use the [`fopen()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fopen) function. Which will return the `FILE` stream.

Comment: Note that the man page is badly laid out but gives two declarations for `open()`:  _`int open(const char *pathname, int flags);int open(const char *pathname,
int flags, mode_t mode);int creat(const char *pathname, mode_t mode);`_  The second one must be used if the `flags` argument include the `O_CREAT` bit.  The POSIX specification for [`open()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open.html)
uses: `int open(const char *path, int oflag, ...);` — explicitly declaring it as a varargs function.  However, only the 2- and 3- argument calls shown at die.net are valid.

Comment: Instead of linking to linux.die.net (which is also outdated), just link to the official one: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html