# Receive data From Text file in C

Tags: c

I have an assignment .
I need to recive Data from a text file into an array of structures (in func,not in main).
struct

```
>#define INPUT_FILE "c:\\in.txt"
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
typedef struct
{
 int serial;
 char name[15];
 char dest[20];
 int taken;
 int date;
}flight;


void flights()
{
    FILE *fin;
   int taken,date,serial;
   char name[15],dest[20];
    fin=fopen(INPUT_FILE,"r");
    if (fin=NULL)
    {
        printf("Eror in opening file %s\n",INPUT_FILE);
        exit(1);
    }
    fscanf(fin,"%d",&serial);
    fgets(name,15,fin);
    fgets(dest,20,fin);
    fscanf(fin,"%d%d",&taken,&date);

}
```

I don't know how to import the date from the text file into the array of structures.
Thanks all

Comment: Text files can not send their contents, thus, one can not receive data from text files

Comment: possible duplicate of [In C, how should I read a text file and print all strings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3463426/in-c-how-should-i-read-a-text-file-and-print-all-strings)

Comment: It will not solve the issue, but it's `if (fin==NULL)`

Comment: You don't have an array of that structure in your code. That complicates things, as it depends (somewhat) on how you create it: statically? dynamically? fixed size, or automatically resizing to fit the number of entries?