# Read - Write Txt File in C

Tags: c, text-files, scanf

I am trying to read - write a txt file that has several info in different lines.
It is in the form of:

```
Number-LicencePlate NumberOfSeats

Name  number  phonenumber

Name  number  phonenumber

Name  number  phonenumber
```

To read the first line it is pretty easy using fscanf
But how can I read the rest of it using fscanf to obtain 3 different variables (Name,Number,phone)?

Write to this file in the same form comes at a later stage but will try to work it out..

```
FILE *bus;
bus = fopen ("bus.txt","r");
if (bus == NULL)
{
    printf("Error Opening File, check if file bus.txt is present");
    exit(1);
}
fscanf(bus,"%s %d",platenr, &numberofseats); 
printf("Bus Licence plate Nr is: %s and number of seats is: %d", platenr, numberofseats);
```

Comment: Tons of duplicates here: https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+read+text+file+using+fscanf+site%3Astackoverflow.com

Comment: Use a while loop!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In C, how should I read a text file and print all strings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3463426/in-c-how-should-i-read-a-text-file-and-print-all-strings)

Comment: I can use a while loop, but how would I skip the first line to loop through the rest of the file? I have found that it can be done this way: fscanf(config_file, "%*[^\n]\n", NULL);

Comment: Write good error messages: `char *path = "bus.txt"; bus = fopen(path, "r"); if(bus==NULL){ perror(path); exit(1);}`  The system error is important (does the file not exist, or is it a permission issue?  Don't make the user guess, just tell them) and belongs on stderr.

Comment: Do not use `scanf`.  If you are learning C, it is more helpful to use `fgets` and parse the data with `strtof`, `strtoll`, etc.  If you know C, it is usually easier to do so.  The *only* function `scanf` has is to confuse people when they are learning the language.

Comment: Ok thank you so much! Yes I think I have found a solution (fingers crossed), using fgets! Probably will just read the first line with fscanf and then the rest with fgets! Will update with my results!

Answer (score 1):

You should use a loop in order to achieve what you are looking for as your code is not reading anything except the first line as `"FILE *bus;"` is a pointer to the first line of the text file.

In order to read it all you can use a simple while loop by checking End of File(EOF). There are 2 methods that I am aware of and here they are;

```
  while(!feof(bus)){
       fscanf(bus,"%s %d",platenr, &numberofseats);
       printf("Bus Licence plate Nr is: %s and number of seats is: %d", platenr, numberofseats);
    }
```

This code block will print each line after reading it.
We have used "feof ( FILE * stream );" function [Learn More Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xssktc6e.aspx). There are also alternative ways suggested on other articles [How to read a whole text file](https://www.google.com/search?q=how%20to%20read%20text%20file%20using%20fscanf%20site%3Astackoverflow.com)

But I will put it here that solution as well.

```
  while(fscanf(bus,"%s %d",platenr, &numberofseats)!=EOF){
        printf("Bus Licence plate Nr is: %s and number of seats is: %d", platenr, numberofseats);
    }
```

[c](/questions/tagged/c)