# how to make fscanf, scan a single word instead of whole line

Tags: c, file-handling

There is a text file called **1.txt** like below that contains certain names, I want to add them to a linked list however the code doesn't scan only one name but the whole line, how can I make `fscanf` so that it only scans a single name?

Example 1.txt:

```
ana,bob,max,dolores
```

My code:

```
FILE *fp = fopen("1.txt", "rt");
while (!feof(fp)) {
    char name_in[100];
    fscanf(fp, "%s,", name_in);
    printf("%s", name_in);
    addnewnode(head, name_in);
}
fclose(fp);
```

Comment: something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12911299/read-csv-file-in-c) ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In C, how should I read a text file and print all strings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3463426/in-c-how-should-i-read-a-text-file-and-print-all-strings)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that with the `"%s"` format, then `scanf` will not stop scanning until it hit the end of the input or a whitespace. That means you can't use `scanf` alone to parse your input.

Instead I suggest you read your whole line into a buffer, for example using [`fgets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets). Once you have it then you can use [`strtok`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok) in a loop to *tokenize* the line.

---

Not using `scanf` also sidesteps a big problem with your format string: Namely that it will look for a trailing comma in the input. If there's no comma at the end of the line (like in your example) then `scanf` will just block. It will block until there is a comma, but if you don't give it a comma then it might block forever. Either that or you will not get the last entry because `scanf` will fail. Checking what [`scanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) returns is crucial.

Also, I strongly suggest you read [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong).

Comment: but i did put a comma (,) before the %s doesn't that count for something?

Comment: @ArashArbabi that just means a string followed by a comma, but a string can contain a comma, so it's ignored

Comment: @ArashArbabi No, the `"%s"` format is *greedy* and will read until it hits a space or the end of the input. *Then* it will attempt to match your trailing comma.

Comment: is there anyway that I could do this without using strtok?

Comment: @ArashArbabi Of course there is. For example by reading one character at a time, append them into a buffer, and use the (*terminated*) buffer when you hit a comma, end of line or end of file.

Answer (score 0):

[**What's in a name?**](https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-personal-names)

A name is usually thought of as containing letters, maybe spaces and some other characters.  Code needs to be told what `char` make up a name, what are valid delimiters and handle *other* unexpected `char`.

`"%s"` only distinguishes between white-space and non-white-space.  It treats `,` the same as letters.

`"%width[A-Za-z' ]"` will define a *scanset* accepting letters, `'` and space.  It will read/save up to `width` characters before appending a *null character*.

Always a good idea to check the return value of a input function *before* using the populated objects.

```
FILE *fp = fopen("1.txt", "rt");
if (fp == NULL) Handle_Error();

// end-of-file signal is not raised until after a read attempt.
// while (!feof(fp)) {

char name_in[100];
char delimiter[2];
int count;
while ((count = fscanf(fp, "%99[A-Za-z' ]%1[,\n]", name_in, delimiter)) == 2) {
  printf("<%s>%s", name_in, delimiter);
  addnewnode(head, name_in);
  if (delimiter[0] == '\n') {
    ; // Maybe do something special at end-of-line
  }
}
fclose(fp);

// Loop stopped unexpectedly
if (count != EOF || !feof(fp)) {
  puts("Oops");
}
```

More robust code would read the *line* like with `fgets()` and then process the string.  Could use similar code as above but with `sscanf()`

---

To include `-` in a *scanset* so code can handle hyphenated names, list it first.  You may want to allow other characters too.

`"%width[-A-Za-z' .]"`