# How to search all particular contents from record in c

Tags: c

I have written a simple code for finding all the records with the same name. However, I am only getting one record. I am not able to find the error.

```
void recsearch()
{
    FILE *fp;
    char emp[50];
    fp=fopen("C:\\New folder\\babarecord.dat","r");

    printf("Name of record : ");
    gets(emp);
    rewind(fp);
    while (fread(&a,sizeof(a),1,fp)!=NULL)
    {
        if(strcmp(a.name,emp)==0)
        {
            printf("%s   %s  %f\n\n\n\n",a.name,a.date,a.amount);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Succesfully printed everything");
            getch();
        }
    }

}
```

`babarecord.dat` contains records like

```
  sam     565    656
  ram     7565   5686
  sam     789    5658
```

Comment: Can you show the content of `babarecord.dat`

Comment: It jst simply contents records

Comment: visibly in your previous (deteled) remark your file contains external representations, not dumps of the struct, you cannot read your struct  though _fread_. Your _else_ case has no sense, it is not because the name is not the expected one you "Succesfully printed everything", not also in that case you execute a _getch_ whose can block the execution and letting you imagining "getting only one record". why the _rewind_ ? when you open you are at the beginning

Comment: Also do not use _gets_ because you can write out of the receiving array, use _fgets_. If you want to be able to enter several names you have to add a loop (cotaining the rewind and the rest of the code, except the else branch)

Comment: Since the file is formatted as text, you should use `fscanf()` to read it, not `fread()`.

Comment: Binary file should be opened in binary mode

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In C, how should I read a text file and print all strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3463426/in-c-how-should-i-read-a-text-file-and-print-all-strings)

Comment: See [Why gets() is so dangerous it should never be used!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-dangerous-why-should-it-not-be-used)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> in below codes i am getting only one record...rather than i need to find all one

The file you give contains external representations, not dumps of the (hidden) *struct*, you cannot use *fread* to read the contents.

You say you got one, the format indicates one field is a _float, it is impossible you read right a float value, also the read name cannot contains miraculously a null character to end it so *strcmp* will not returns 0, and it is also very probably impossible the size of your *struct* is compatible with the size of each line newline included because they seems have different length. For me you never find the expected record.

The *else* branch printing "Succesfully printed everything" has no sense, this is not because *strcmp* does not return 0 that you finished to read all the records then printed everything. In that case you also call  *getch* whose blocks the execution in case all buffered inputs was read.

The *rewind* is useless because you just open the file, so you are at its beginning.

You read the name of the record using *gets*, that function is deprecated sinse a long time because very dangerous, it has no protection against the fact you write the input out of the receiving array of character.

---

A way can be (the file is given in parameter rather than to have its pathname given through a literal string in the code) including a probable definition of the *struct* compatible with the code you give :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct Record {
  char name[50];
  char date[10];
  float amount;
} Record;

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
  if (argc != 2)
    printf("Usage: %s <file>\n", *argv);
  else {
    FILE * fp = fopen(argv[1],"r");

    if (fp == NULL)
      fprintf(stderr, "cannot open \"%s\"\n", argv[1]);
    else {
      char emp[50];

      printf("Name of record : ");

      if (scanf("%49s", emp) == 1) { /* or use fgets then remove the newline */
        Record a;

        while (fscanf(fp, "%49s %9s %f", a.name, a.date, &a.amount) == 3) {
          if(strcmp(a.name, emp)==0)
            printf("%s %s %f\n", a.name, a.date, a.amount);
        }

        puts("all was read");
        /* add getch(); if you want */
      }

      fclose(fp);
    }
  }
}
```

with your file *babarecord.dat*, compilation and executions

```
gcc  -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Werror c.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
Usage: ./a.out <file>
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out babarecord.dat
Name of record : aze
all was read
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out babarecord.dat
Name of record : sam
sam 565 656.000000
sam 789 5658.000000
all was read
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out babarecord.dat
Name of record : ram
ram 7565 5686.000000
all was read
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

P.S. 565, 7565 and 789 are strange dates