# Looping input request from a char array in C

Tags: arrays, c, loops, input, cs50

When running the program and entering the text, it will ask me again and again to insert the input, until I give an input of one character only.

NOTE: it isn't in any sort of cycle loop, I don't know what the problem is. (I'm using cs50 library for the get char).

```
char nameless[] = { get_char("Insert the text here: ")};
```

Comment: because the name tells that is a function to get one character only... https://man.cs50.io/3/get_char

Comment: why `c` and `c#` in the tags?  This looks like it is neither.

Comment: it's c, I'm following a cs50 course

Answer (score 1):

```
char nameless[] = {get_char("Insert the text here: ")};
```

If you look up `get_char()`, it clearly states

> Prompts user for a line of text from standard input and returns the equivalent char; if text does not represent a **single** char, user is **reprompted**.

You need to enter only **one** character. Not a line of characters or 'text' as you call it.

```
Enter char: a
```

That's it.

Here's a working code example:

```
#include <cs50.h>

int main(void)
{
     // attempt to read character from stdin
     char c = get_char("Enter char: ");

     // ensure character was read successfully
     if (c == CHAR_MAX)
     {
         return 1;
     }

     char next = get_char("You just entered %c. Enter another char: ", c);

     if (next == CHAR_MAX)
     {
        return 1;
     }

     printf("The last char you entered was %c\n", next);
 }
```

You can look it up at [CS50 Library for C](https://cs50.readthedocs.io/libraries/cs50/c/#c.get_char)

Comment: thanks, but my program requires a text (like from a book page) in input, so entering one character at time isn't what I'm looking for. Sorry but I'm new to programming.

Comment: @markC that's totally not an issue. The best way to learn is to look things up. Also, please ask in your question **exactly** what you need. To take in a whole page of text and print it, take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3463426/in-c-how-should-i-read-a-text-file-and-print-all-strings

Comment: Thanks for understanding, I need to take in input a long text (like from a book Page) but not from a file but from the user's keyboard (like scanner), and then put that input in a char array (because I Need to count letters, words an sentences, but that's not a problem, I've already done that, I only Need to put that input in the array.)

Comment: There's a ` get_string()` function, is there not, in the CS50 library.  It returns a ”`string`” which is a `char *` in disguise.