# Why does this code only print the first line of the file?

Tags: c, file, structure

The requirements:

Write a C program that executes the following tasks in order:

- Initially displays the content of the file in the execution window
- Ask the user for an ID, search for the ID in the file then display a message (in the execution window) in the following format: Student with ID:……… corresponds to ………………. who is majoring in………………
  As you print the name of the student in the output, do not print ‘_’!

The problem:
It only outputs the first line (aka first student info) from the file, and it does not even ask for the student ID afterward.

The code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
typedef struct {
    int ID;
    char Last_name[30], First_name[30], major[30];
} Class;
int search_for_student(int ID_to_search, Class students[22]) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 22; i++) {
        if (students[i].ID == ID_to_search)
            return i;
    }
    return -101;
}
void main(void) {
    char line[100];
    int  ID_to_search, i, index, j;
    Class students[22];
    FILE* infp;
    infp = fopen("Section_06.txt", "r");
    if (infp == NULL) {
        printf("File unexistant!\n");
    }
    else {
        for (i = 0; i < 22; i++) {
            fscanf(infp, "%d", students[i].ID);
            printf("%d", students[i].ID);
            fscanf(infp, "%s", students[i].Last_name);
            for (j = 0; j < strlen(students[i].Last_name); j++) {
                if (students[i].Last_name[j] == '_')
                    students[i].Last_name[j] = ' ';
            }
            printf("%s", students[i].Last_name);
            fscanf(infp, "%s", students[i].First_name);
            for (j = 0; j < strlen(students[i].First_name); j++) {
                if (students[i].First_name[j] == '_')
                    students[i].First_name[j] = ' ';
            }
            printf("%s", students[i].First_name);
            fgets(students[i].major, 30, infp);
            printf("%s", students[i].major);
        }
        printf("Enter an ID: ");
        scanf("%d", &ID_to_search);
        index = search_for_student(ID_to_search, students);
        if (index == -101)
            printf("Student not found!");
        else {
            printf("Student with ID: %d corresponds to %s %s who is majoring in %s.", students[index].ID, students[index].First_name, students[index].Last_name, students[index].major);
        }
    }
    fclose(infp);
}
```

Comment: Please _edit_ your question and post some representative input data in a separate code block here.

Comment: I would start by learning a serviceable way to read a file.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3463426/in-c-how-should-i-read-a-text-file-and-print-all-strings) for a representative example.

Comment: regarding: `void main(void) {`  if your compiler is allowing this statement, then it is a non-compilant compiler!  There are only two valid signatures for `main()`  They are: `int main( void )` and `int main( int argc, char *argv[] )`

Comment: regarding statements like: `for (j = 0; j < strlen(students[i].Last_name); j++) {`   this is comparing a unsigned value with a signed value.  ( `j` is a `int` and the function: `strlen()` returns a `size_t` which is unsigned)  This will only work correctly for small positive values

Comment: OT: the posted code contains several 'magic' numbers: I.E. 22, 30, 100.  'magic' numbers make the code much more difficult to understand, debug, etc.  Suggest using `#define` statements or a `enum` statement to give those 'magic' numbers meaningful names, then use those meaningful names throughout the code.

Comment: OT: regarding: `typedef struct 
{
    int ID;
    char Last_name[30];
    char First_name[30];
    char major[30];
} Class;`  this struct has no 'tag' name, so most debuggers cannot display the fields within the struct.  Suggest adding a 'tag' name.  Also, it is a poor programming practice to use reserved words (with a variation in the capitalization) for a variable name

Comment: OT: regarding: `int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 22; i++)`  one of the objectives of good programming practice is to limit the scope of variables. Therefore, suggest: `for ( int i = 0; i < 22; i++)` so the scope of the variable `i` is limited to the body of the `for()` statement.

Comment: OT: regarding statements like: `int  ID_to_search, i, index, j;`  Pllease follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*

Comment: OT:  regarding: `printf("File unexistant!\n");`  Error messages should be output to `stderr`, not `stdout` and when the error indication is from a C library function, should also output to `stderr` the text reason the system thinks the error occurred.  The function `perror()` is made for that purpose.  Also, since the call to `fopen()` failed, there is nothing more to do than 'cleanup' and exit, probably via `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`  Calling `fclose()` on the file that not open is an error than can cause your program to crash

Comment: OT: regarding statements like: `fscanf(infp, "%d", students[i].ID);`  This statement can fail!  always check the returned value (not the parameter values).  The `scanf()` family of functions returns the number of successful 'input format conversion' specifiers.  Suggest: `if( fscanf(infp, "%d", students[i].ID) != 1 ) { handle the error }`

Comment: OT: regarding statements like: `fscanf(infp, "%s", students[i].First_name);`  When using the `input format conversion specifier: `%s` (and/or %[...]) always include a MAX_CHARACTERS modifier that is 1 less than the length of the input buffer, because those specifiers always append a NUL byte to the input.  This avoids any possibility of a buffer overflow and the resulting undefined behavior

Answer (score 1):

there are several points:

1. main should return int
2. fscanf(info, "%d", &students[I].ID); // '&' has been missed.
3. the file read loop

   for (i = 0; i < 22; i++)

is not good.

```
while(fgets(buff, sizeof(buff), infp)!=NULL){
}
```

should be better. the file might have more or less lines;

4. it's not good to combine fscanf with gets. please use fgets to read line and sscanf or strtok to get fields.

Answer (score 0):

You miss an `&` on this line:

```
fscanf(infp, "%d", students[i].ID);
```

Change to:

```
fscanf(infp, "%d", &students[i].ID);
```

Answer (score 0):

regarding:

*The problem: It only outputs the first line (aka first student info) from the file, and it does not even ask for the student ID afterward.*

the code of interest is

```
    printf("Enter an ID: ");
    scanf("%d", &ID_to_search);
    index = search_for_student(ID_to_search, students);
    
    if (index == -101)
        printf("Student not found!");
    else {
        printf("Student with ID: %d corresponds to %s %s who is majoring in %s.", students[index].ID, students[index].First_name, students[index].Last_name, students[index].major);
    } 
}  // end if/else, not the end of a `for() loop
```

Notice that the above code is the end of a 'else' code block, not part of a `for()` loop, so only will be executed once

Also, if less than 22 students to input, the call to `fscanf()` will return EOF rather than updating any student info.  Are you sure the input file actually contains 22 instances of student info?  does it even contain more than 1 instance of student info?

rather than using a hardcoded count of 22, for:

```
for (i = 0; i < 22; i++) 
    {
        fscanf(infp, "%d", students[i].ID);
```

suggest using the returned value from that first call to `fscanf()` similar to:

```
i = 0;
while( fscanf(infp, "%d", students[i].ID) != EOF )
{
    ....
    i++;
}
```